# Make first letter of child name capital in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I push data to Firebase using Order object, the question is I want the first letter of every child name capital. I defined the property like "Complain" but in Firebase it still shows as "complain", I dont know how to make it.

The current structure of the Firebase:

[image: The current structure of the Firebase]

The structure I want:

[image: The structure I want]

I defined the property like this:

```
@Data
public class Order implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("Complain")
private String Complain;

public Order() {
 Complain = "";
}

public String getComplain() {
    return Complain;
}

public void setComplain(String complain) {
    Complain = complain;
}
}
```

I push data to Firebase like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(orderSavePath, order);
reference.updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(listener);
```

Comment: Did u try setComplain(String Complain)?

Comment: show your full model class and how u setting value in firebase ..

Comment: @uguboz yes, but it didnt work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Firebase JSON serialization name is controlled by the [annotation `PropertyName`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName).

```
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private String Complain;

    public Order() {
     Complain = "";
    }

    @PropertyName("Complain")
    public String getComplain() {
        return Complain;
    }

    @PropertyName("Complain")
    public void setComplain(String complain) {
        Complain = complain;
    }

}
```

The annotation needs to be on both the getter and the setter. Alternatively you can just use public fields and reduce the class to:

```
public class Order {
    @PropertyName("Complain")
    public String Complain;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.