# Getting null while getting data from Firebase RTD

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a simple app that can sign-in/sign-up.

Everything works normally except when I try to get data from the "Users" path on Realtime Database, I always get null for UID even though I already pushed my data and this is not a too complex part and I can get data normally with the exact same type others data?

This is the part where i define User object:

```
public class User {

    String profile_picture_url , username , user_email, user_uid;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String profile_picture_url , String userUID , String username,String user_email)
    {
        this.profile_picture_url = profile_picture_url;
        this.user_uid = userUID;
        this.username = username;
        this.user_email = user_email;
    }

    //GETTER
    public String getProfile_picture_url() {
        return profile_picture_url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getUser_EMail() {
        return user_email;
    }

    public String getUserUID() {
        return user_uid;
    }
}
```

This is my json tree on Firebase:
[image]

This is the part where I retrieve the data:

```
private void readUserFromFB() {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Log.d("firebase_debug2",firebaseUser.getUid());
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);

                Log.d("firebase_debug2", " This is email " + user.getUser_EMail());
                Log.d("firebase_debug2","This is uid " + user.getUserUID());
                Log.d("firebase_debug2", "This is username " + user.getUsername());

              
                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), userList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

Get this in logcat:

```
This is email tas@gmail.com
This is uid null
This is username tas
This is email wwqw@gmail.com
This is uid null
This is username wiiwi
```

Why do I get that annoying problem, hope somebody can help me find out because I tried for hours but can't figure out where I've missed.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property in the JSON of the database is called `user_uid`, but in your Java code you have:

```
public String getUserUID() {
    return user_uid;
}
```

Firebase follows JavaBean property naming conventions, so the getter for property `user_uid` should be:

```
public String getUser_uid() {
    return user_uid;
}
```

Similarly the setter should be `setUser_uid(String newUid)`, or the field should be `user_uid` if that is public.

Alternatively you can change the property name in the JSON to `userUID`, so that it matches your code, or use annotations to explicitly tell Firebase the name of the property in the database:

```
@PropertyName("user_uid")
public String getUserUID() {
    return user_uid;
}
```

Also check out:

- [Firebase @PropertyName doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work)
- [Firebase serialization names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306168/firebase-serialization-names/45330351#45330351)
- [Make first letter of child name capital in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809197/make-first-letter-of-child-name-capital-in-firebase/45809982#45809982)
- [Firebase @PropertyName doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work/46820755#46820755), in case you (or someone else who finds this) is having the same problem in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem and helped me learn something new.